# Why is Visual Studio forcing StackNode two different ways?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, data-structures, linked-list, stack

So I wrote a Linked List based implementation of the Stack ADT recently. However, I'm not quite sure why there is a bit of a discrepancy between how the nodes of the Stack are being declared. The compiler gets very angry and won't compile until I write them a certain way for certain functions. I'm extremely curious as to why this is the case.

Here are two different methods which the compiler wants two different formats.

Here is my destructor where the compiler wants `StackNode *temp`.

```
template <typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType>::~StackLinked() {
   StackNode *temp;
   while (top != 0) {
       temp = top;
       top = top->next;
       delete temp;
   }
}
```

Here is my assignment operator overload where the compiler wants `StackNode<DataType> *temp`.

```
template <typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType>& StackLinked<DataType>::operator=(const StackLinked& other) {
    if (this != &other) {
        StackNode<DataType> *newNode, *current, *last;

        if (top != 0) {
           StackNode<DataType> *temp;
           while (top != 0) {
               temp = top;
               top -> top->next;
               delete temp;
           }
        }

        if (other.top == 0) {
            top = 0;
        }
        else {
            current = other.top;
            top = new StackNode<DataType>;
            top->dataItem = current->dataItem;
            top->next = 0;
            last = top;
            current = current->next;

            while (current != 0) {
                newNode = new StackNode<DataType>;
                newNode->dataItem = current->dataItem;
                newNode->next = 0;
                last-> next = newNode;
                last = newNode;
                current = current->next;
            }
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

I don't know why this is, but the unknown is bothering me.

Note: My StackNode class is an inner class of the StackLinked class.

EDIT: Class declaration:

```
#ifndef STACKARRAY_H
#define STACKARRAY_H

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#include "Stack.h"

template <typename DataType>
class StackLinked : public Stack<DataType> {

public:

StackLinked(int maxNumber = Stack<DataType>::MAX_STACK_SIZE);
StackLinked(const StackLinked& other);
StackLinked& operator=(const StackLinked& other);
~StackLinked();

void push(const DataType& newDataItem) throw (logic_error);
DataType pop() throw (logic_error);

void clear();

bool isEmpty() const;
bool isFull() const;

void showStructure() const;

private:
class StackNode {
  public:
StackNode(const DataType& nodeData, StackNode* nextPtr);
DataType dataItem;
StackNode* next;
};

StackNode* top;
};

#endif
```

If any other details are needed. Just ask! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can we see your class declaration?  Is your assignment operator properly declared?

Comment: By my basic test g++ 4.7.2 seems to be happy with `StackNode *temp;`

Comment: I updated my question with the class declaration per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you showed, `StackNode<DataType>` is not correct, because `StackNode` is not a class template.

This makes me think you have a template also named `StackNode` that the compiler is finding.  Go check whether any of your files contain another version of `StackNode`.

Comment: Funny thing is that when I hover my cursor over StackNode<DataType> Visual Studio says that it is coming from StackLinked<DataType>::StackNode. Yet the compiler is still accepting it. This is the one and only version of StackNode that I have ever created.